# Excel 365 Find and Replace modifies column formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace, text-formatting

I have a column in spreadsheet set to 'text' format that looks like this: xxxxxx057483245

I am attemtping to replace the x's with another series of numbers.   42424242 for example.

I go to find and replace, and enter in the 6 x's to be replaced by the new numbers.    The result I get in the replaced column is 4242424057483240.  Note the 5 has been replaced with a 0.

I have attempted to play around with the column formatting trying to use text, general and number with 0 decimal places with no luck.   Any ideas?   I know how to get around it, but thought I should try and seek the answer for posterity.

Comment: As a FYI, my workaround was to save the XLS file as a CSV and do the F&R in a standard text editor.   Pretty easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place an **apostrophe** *(single quote)* in front of the replacement digits.

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Comment: I'll give that a try, but out of curiosity, what is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: @TaylorAckley  The single quote tells Excel to treat the value as Text and avoids the 15-digit limit.